# UI Components don't render in SWT when using NVIDIA graphics card in windows 7

Tags: swt, nvidia

I am running an eclipse based application in windows 7. Few of the components do not render when I use nvidia graphics card on windows 7. They render properly when I use a different graphics card. Can anyone suggest the possible causes for this issues.

I am using NVIDIA NVS 300 graphics card.

Thanks

Comment: A screenshot or some information about "do not render" would be appreciated.

Comment: attaching screenshot of the issue...please note how the Treeviewer is not shown.
http://www.4shared.com/photo/yUnKUk8t/doesnt_work.html

http://www.4shared.com/photo/s30ydujP/works.html

Comment: Is that the same OS in both screenshots, i.e. same version of windows?

Comment: no one is in xp and other is 7...but i can reproduce the problem in xp and in 7...

Comment: Does it happen with all nvidia cards or just the one mentioned? Does it happen on all nvidia nvs 300 cards?

Comment: it happens on all nvs 300 cards..I don't know about other nvidia cards..it doesn't happen on other graphics card....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the video driver?  I've run many eclipse based apps on Win 7 with NVidia cards without a problem.

Comment: I've updated the driver...most of my application runs fine, all the components render correctly. But when I bring up a dialog few of the components don't render...m still debugging to figure out the issue...

Comment: While debugging..i figured out that the paint event wasn't being called on some of the widgets...seems quite weird why it would happen on this particular graphics card and not others...so i forcefully had the parent layout itself again...